# Redshift aliasing in FROM clause in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have a CTE `converted` which returns column `provider_ids` as an array of quoted numbers. (The SUPER type in Redshift). I need to perform the unnesting syntax in Redshift by aliasing the CTE and then referencing the alias in the same FROM clause. Below is the working Redshift query.

I'm unsure if this is possible using SQLAlchemy. Using session.execute() with raw SQL is frowned upon at my workplace so I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

```
select
    converted_ids.*, provider_id
from
    converted converted_ids, converted_ids.provider_ids provider_id
```

I found the syntax for this at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest

Comment: Can you share your CTE as well?

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with one of the core developers in the library's IRC channel, it seems there is no first class support currently for this type of syntax. Any usage of it would require executing the SQL as pure text which would mean having no access to any of the ORM features.